# I'm using CSS Grid with three columns but they don't grow with the content despite being set to 100%

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've literally tried everything at this point, but something in my code is making my website act funny. I've set it up to accept a picture with a very tall resolution to fill the center column of my CSS grid with the other two acting as margins. When I do this with my current code, the picture overflows the grid and when I scroll the margins just stop half way down the page. The container grows to size with the height of the photo but my margins don't.
Here's a picture of my website scrolled down half way, the cream colored part is the container and the black part is where the margins stop.

Picture of website:
[image]

Thanks for any advice if someone has some!

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
}


  
.content {
    width: 70vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #252525;
}

.margin {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000000;
}

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}

p {
    color: #45d163;
    font-size: 2.5vh;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
  background-color: #fceee3;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;

}
.grid-item {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 0%;

  
}
 .grid-center {
  background-color: #252525;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30vh;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 0%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Keyboard Mechanic</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> </link>

    <style>

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #171615;
  padding: 1% 1%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  
  
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  width: 8vw;
  margin-right: 10px;
 
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  width: 8vw;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
}

.header a.logo {
  all: unset;
}

.login {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  width: 8vw;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}



.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 100%) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    
  }
 }
</style>

<style>
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto fit-content(70%) auto;
  background-color: #fceee3;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0%;
  
}
 .grid-center {
  background-color: #252525;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0%;

}

</style>


  </head>
    
  <body>  
      <div class="header">
          <a href="newLook.html" class="logo"> <img src="images/cornerlogo.png" height="50px"> </a>
          <div class="header-right">
          <a class="active" href="newLook.html">Home</a>
          <a class="active" href="games.html">Games</a>
          <a class="active" href="webprojects.html">Web Projects</a>
          <a class="login"  href="login.html">Login</a>
          <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          <a href="about.html" style="margin-right: 2vw;">About</a>
    
          </div>
       </div>
 
      <div class="wrapper"> 
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        
        <div class="grid-center"> 
        
            <img src="images/homepageFour.png" width="100%"> </img>
        
        </div>
        
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
      
      </div>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
<!-- partial -->
```

Comment: The width of the image determines the width of that div. So, you can fix a width for its parent div.

Comment: The width attribute (as opposed to the CSS width property) does not take units.

Comment: I have that column set as auto for the width, before that I set it as fit-content with similar results to now

Comment: I made sure to address the width attribute, but it doesn't make a difference. To clarify the problem is I can't get the black margins to stretch the entire height of the page, the width proportions are fine with me.

Comment: Also, if you run the code snippet you can't see the problem, it's only visible in the picture!

Answer (score 0):

The second selector is valid because the [specificity value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector named ".header a" is lower than the specificity value of the selector named ".header a.active".

If you want to almost maximize the specificity value, you have to: use **!important**.

```css
.header a {
  width: max-content !important;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn’t work, all it did was shift around the size of the buttons a bit. I’m trying to get the black margins as seen in the picture to stretch the height of the page when I scroll down.

Comment: @JacobRodriguez Sorry mate. I thought the problem was in the button. Can you indicate where exactly the problem is in the picture?

By the way, if the problem is with the images, I should mention that your images are not visible.

Comment: Hey, so the issue isn't visible when you run the code, but if you check the image I linked you can see that the bottom half of the margin space is white instead of black. That's because the container has grown while the margins haven't, I can't figure out how to make them scale to the content I put on the page.

Comment: If you are setting the background via *CSS*: [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and [background-repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) properties; If you added an image with *img* tag via *HTML*, you should try [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) feature. If there is still a problem, correct your code and add an external, representative image for the background. I will check it.